# Twilio IVR Disconnects After Voice Input

Tags: ivr

I've created an IVR flow using the provided template. I did not make any changes to it, however, it does NOT work. If I press 1 for sales or 2 for support, it works fine.

If I say "sales" or "support" the call just ends. I'm using Twilio studio and do not intend on doing any coding, but I don't understand why the "out of the box" template doesn't even work?

Answer (score 0):

Noobie here too, I was having the same problem with the out-of-the-box template. I figured out how to upload my own mp3 (mp4 didn't work) audio file and got that working....but I was stumped on the speech recognition part pretty bad:

Make sure you include a period after the word... I noticed this after starting from scratch with a new template...The first time I edited the Call Tree Template for the first time I got too far in it to figure this out sooner.... 5 hours later searching the net for answers and awaiting a ticket reply I found a doc that mentioned when using the "Matches Any Of" transition you might want to try it... What a nice official suggestion (Twilio law I suppose)! I just put both and it  works perfectly, for example:

"1, 1., Uno, Uno., Una, Una., Uno, Uno., Español, Español., Español, Español., Español, Español."